# Python/Regex: Split string if a line does contain a certain special character

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to split a multiline string on a character but only if the line does not contain `:`. Unfortunately I can't see an easy way to use `re.split()` with negative lookback on the character `:` since it's possible that `:` occurred in another line earlier in the string.

As an example, I'd like to split the below string on `)`.

**String:**

```
Hello1 (
First : (),
Second )

Hello2 (
First 
)
```

**Output:**

```
['Hello1 (\nFirst : (),\nSecond', 'Hello2 (\nFirst \n']
```

Comment: I am not sure if it is even possible to achieve this just using Regex. I will be surprised if somebody comes up with an answer.

Comment: ( @AmitSingh ) it's possible in some Regex engines, e.g. in PowerShell / .Net it works to `$string -split '(?m)(?<=^[^:]+)\)'` but Python doesn't seem to support variable length lookbehind matches and that rules out this approach. I can't think of a way past that with just Regex.

Comment: An approach I could use would be to split by a newline character `\n` and then use regex lookbehind on the line string but this wouldn't be robust in my case

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: Shamelessly used your expression with the newer `regex` module but have provided others as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible with `Python`, albeit not "out of the box" with the native `re` module.

### First alternative

The newer [**`regex` module**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) supports a variable-length lookbehind, so you could use

```
(?<=^[^:]+)\)
# pos. lookbehind making sure there's no : in that line
```

---

In `Python`:

```
import regex as re

data = """
Hello1 (
First : (),
Second )

Hello2 (
First 
)"""

pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=^[^:]+)\)', re.MULTILINE)

parts = pattern.split(data)
print(parts)
```

Which yields

```
['\nHello1 (\nFirst : (),\nSecond ', '\n\nHello2 (\nFirst \n', '']
```

---

### Second alternative

Alternatively, you could match the lines in question and let them fail with `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` afterwards:

```
^[^:\n]*:.*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\)
# match lines with at least one : in it
# let them fail
# or match )
```

---

Again in `Python`:

```
pattern2 = re.compile(r'^[^:\n]*:.*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\)', re.MULTILINE)
parts2 = pattern.split(data)
print(parts2)
```

See [**a demo for the latter on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Rwzg3m/1).

---

### Third alternative

Ok, now the answer is getting longer than previously thought. You can even do it with the native `re` module with the help of a function. Here, you need to substitute the `)` in question first and split by the substitute:

```
def replacer(match):
    if match.group(1) is not None:
        return "SUPERMAN"
    else:
        return match.group(0)

pattern3 = re.compile(r'^[^:\n]*:.*|(\))', re.MULTILINE)
data = pattern3.sub(replacer, data)
parts3 = data.split("SUPERMAN")
print(parts3)
```

Comment: I have never seen `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` before, that's a really interesting one.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: Indeed, it is very powerful for matching patterns only in specific situations.

Comment: @Jan wow, thank you for your different solutions to this. Like TessellatingHeckler, I've never seen the usage of `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`. Solution 1 did not work for the more general problem I had so I'm trying to figure out why. But solution 2 did.